# Spam filters: IP address with no history v. good history

Tags: email, spam, spam-filter

Zoho gave me an IP address with no history this week. Senderscore.org says there's insufficient data to evaluate it. At other times Zoho has assigned me an email sending IP with a fair or good score.

I've seen less engagement with cold pitches this week. My domain checks out on email deliverability; I think it may be the IP or something else.

Are more of my emails likely going to spam because the sending IP doesn't have a history? I send a couple dozen pitches a week.

Comment: Unless an overwhelming majority of recipients actually wants the stuff you send, it should not matter in the long run whether you sneakily try to live off the historic experience recipients had with your sending address. Because the ideal amount of unsolicited messages is so close to zero, you do not keep that "no history" status for long with "cold pitches".

Comment: Senderscore.org looks at big volumes. I send low volume - meaning, I may never get a scored IP. I pitch marketers who regularly consider pitches. My pitches are personalized. Does that context help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot goes into deliverability concerns, and you've found one of them: sender volume.

The major email players (Google, Microsoft, what's left of Yahoo) all use some in-house heuristics based on the kinds of traffic they've gotten from a given IP address. If your IP has very little traffic on it, they're going to be more suspicious of that traffic. This also ramps over time; if you get a new IP that has a lot of historic traffic, your low sending rates will degrade reputation over time.

This mechanic is one of several forcing mechanisms that urge small players to get a Google Apps/Office 365 account to send email, since those go out of a major player account with fairly solid reputation.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very helpful answer. I'll consider Google Apps/Office 365. For the record, I follow good deliverability practices. Best wishes